# Jenkins jobs Schedule

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking to schedule a job to run on the 3rd Sunday of every month but haven't found a solution for this yet.

Hopefully someone will give me a suggestion about the Jenkins Cron.

I have tried some things like this:

```
0 25 0 ? 1/1 7#3 *
```

But seem not working with the Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You must set schedule with cron format, This field follows the syntax of cron (with minor differences). Specifically, each line consists of 5 fields separated by TAB or whitespace:

```
MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW
```

that:

```
MINUTE  Minutes within the hour (0–59)
HOUR    The hour of the day (0–23)
DOM The day of the month (1–31)
MONTH   The month (1–12)
DOW The day of the week (0–7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.
```

To specify multiple values for one field, the following operators are available. In the order of precedence,

```
* specifies all valid values
M-N specifies a range of values
M-N/X or */X steps by intervals of X through the specified range or whole valid range
A,B,...,Z enumerates multiple values
```